# How to import a C++20 module from another directory?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++20

I am trying to use the module feature from C++20 since MSVC and GCC11 kinda supports it now. With header files we could put relative/full path of header to include them. But how do we import modules which are in some other folders than the source? Also is there an option in Visual Studio to include the import path or something?

Comment: There's a [Microsoft blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/a-tour-of-cpp-modules-in-visual-studio/) on this. I think it contains the info you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Have a similar problem when trying to reference a module created in another VS solution.

The "producer" solution builds a DLL (or static library) project from which a c++20 module is exported.
The "consumer" solution has project that imports the c++20 module.

Gotcha #1:

Now the consuming project has no notion of the modules defined in the other VS solution. That's why it would've been so much easier when they were living in the same VS solution. But they are not. Otherwise you could use a "Project Reference" which solves this mostly (hint hint!).

For the two solution approach, I found that - just as @bolov's answer says - I need to point the `AdditionalModuleDependencies` compiler setting to the module binary. So not just the path they are created in! I was also expecting it to somehow magically find the file but the current compiler doesn't.

Example:
`<AdditionalModuleDependencies>x:\path\to\intermediate\your_module.ixx.ifc`.
Especially note the `.ixx` part which *must* be part of the name here!
I'd advise to use the common VS macros like `$(IntDir)` to build a relative path to your `.ifc` file instead of specifying an absolute path though.

Gotcha #2:

Even for intra solution module references, you still need to tell the "producer" project that the modules exported are public. Otherwise the module content isn't visible to other project(s).
You can find this setting called `All Modules are Public` under `VC++ Directories`.

Gotcha #3 (for DLL producers only):

You still need to specify `__declspec(dllexport)`, otherwise you will get the infamous linker errors. On the consuming side it is apparently smart enough to realize the module has imports, so there it's just a matter of `import`.

Gotcha #4:

Trying to `import` a module into a precompiled header file while you are also trying to `import` the same module somewhere else (from regular code). You will get `C1199 missing reference to IFC file to resolve an import-declaration`. This is insidious because you might be importing the module indirectly into your precompiled header through some other regular `#include`.

You can expect this bogus error:

```
C1199 missing reference to IFC file to resolve an import-declaration; please ensure proper value for a '/reference' or '/headerUnit' option is provided
```

Gotcha #5:

Using forward declarations in modules. These can indirectly cause linker errors. I've seen this happen but I can't yet explain why.

Gotcha #6:

`Error  C1117   unrecoverable error importing module 'MyModule': symbol 'Foo' has already been defined`

Ordering the `#include` statements often helps. The idea is to include the `deepest` includes first, then import modules and so on.

In other cases I've seen that moving the include that belongs to the cpp unit you're compiling some works better.

So let's say for `myunit.cpp` you have:

```
#include "myunit.h"
#include <dep1.h>
#include <dep2.h>
```

It sometimes works better as:

```
#include <dep1.h>
#include <dep2.h>
#include "myunit.h"  (last)
```

Gotcha #7:

Your file `#includes` a header file from another MSVC project that depends on the project you are currently compiling.
Even without modules this is probably already a bad idea.

Gotcha #8:

Trying to `#include` a file that was already parsed via a module.
Since modules do not export macros the c inclusion guard doesn't work. Now you will get `type redefinition` errors.

It sometimes helps to move the `#include` before the `import` happens that indirectly parses the same file.

Answer (score -1):

From [A Tour of C++ Modules in Visual Studio](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/a-tour-of-cpp-modules-in-visual-studio/) (thanks to JHBonarius):

> Your code can consume modules in the same project or any referenced
> ones automatically (using project-to-project references to static
> library projects).
>
> It is also possible to reference modules that exist on disk, instead
> of ones belonging to another project in the solution. Care needs to be
> taken here, however, because modules are compiled, binary files. You
> must make sure they are compatible with the way you are building your
> projects.
>
> You can tell Visual Studio to look for modules on disk by editing the
> Additional Module Dependencies property:
>
> Configuration Properties >> C++ >> General >> Additional Module
> Dependencies

Comment: This article don't say how to config that, I tried absolute dir but don't work

Comment: The answer is good. Project references work well. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76487138/19497610