# Importing external C++20 modules in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++20, visual-studio-2022, c++-modules

I'm exploring C++20's modules in Visual Studio 2022 and I'm looking into external modules; modules that have been compiled in one project, I'll call it the library project, and are imported in another. To my understanding, this can be done by for example having the library project compile as a static library and generate a `.lib` file, which then can be added as a dependency in the other project. Then, to add module interfaces from the library project, I can add each module interface by adding its corresponding `.ixx.ifc` file to `C/C++ -> Additional Module Dependencies`.

This works fine, but I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing it, as specifying each `.ixx.ifc` file would get messy for large libraries. Perhaps there is a way to combine modules into larger ones that can be imported without the smaller ones having to be imported? I've tried adding a new module and `export import`-ing other modules in it, but I still seem to have to add each of those other modules' `.ixx.ifc` files as dependencies. Or perhaps there is a way to add multiple `.ixx.ifc` files as dependencies at once?

Answer (score 1):

**Project References are Generally Sufficient**

In Visual Studio, project references to dependency projects are generally sufficient.

"...*In most cases, you won't need to specify this switch because the project system discovers module dependencies within a solution automatically*..."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/module-reference?view=msvc-170

---

**Details of the Automatic Module Lookup Process**

Module references are provided to the compiler automatically by a two-phase process.

**Phase I**

The project system generates json files for all imported modules of all projects being built.

(Then, simply by reading all of the module json files in the object output directory(ies), all of the module dependency locations for all of the modules that are imported by all of the sources in the projects that are being built, can be determined. See Phase II).

**Phase II**

At this stage, the build system has the location of the ifc files of every module used across all projects that are being built. With that information, all cl /reference args are automatically added during compilation.

For this reason, adding /reference args is generally not necessary.

https://lists.isocpp.org/sg15/att-1234/C___20_Modules_Build_in_Visual_Studio.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If your projects are in the same solution, for example you have 2 projects, one is the lib project called `util`, the other one is the main project called `main`. If you want `import util;` in the main project, you need to set the `util` project as a reference of `main`.

HOWTO:

In **Solution Explorer**, right click the **References** under the main project tree, click **Add Reference...**, now you can add all projects you need as reference (you can select all reference projects at once).

The bonus part of this approach is, if any code modified in `util`, the `util` project will compile first if you just build the `main` project, the Visual Studio will create a build dependency automatically. You can check it by right click the `main` project in **Solution Explorer**, select **Build Dependencies** -> **Project Dependencies**.

Answer (score -1):

Whether you want to import more than one module at once? If so, I suggest you could try to use `/reference`. To import more than one module, include a separate /reference option for each file. You could refer to the Doc:[/reference (Use named module IFC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/module-reference?view=msvc-170)

Comment: That's what adding a file as an additional module dependency in Visual Studio does. My question was about how to deal with large amounts of ifc files; is there either a way of adding multiple ifc files at once, or combining multiple modules into one ifc file? Or maybe there is some other solution.

Comment: To import more than one module, include a separate /reference option for each file. Refer to the [Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/module-reference?view=msvc-170#examples)
`cl ... /std:c++latest /reference m.ifc /reference m-part.ifc /reference Networking.ifc`

Comment: This is an excellent answer because it pointed me to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/module-reference?view=msvc-170